# How can I update probabilities if an event cannot happen?

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian

Suppose that I have general information (probabilities) for how many yards a football player will run on the football field.

Let $A$ be the event the runner goes 1 yards, $B$ the event the runner goes 2 yards, $C$ the event the runner goes 3 yards and $D$ the event the runner goes 4 yards.

Let $()=0.60$, $()=0.20$, $()=0.1$ and $P(D)=0.1$.

Now, let's assume the runner is actually only 2 yards away from the end zone and so the player cannot exceed 2 yards which means $P(C)$ and $P(D)$ cannot happen.

Also, if the player has gone 2 yards, that means that they went 1 yard, and if they player went 3 yards they also went 1 & 2 yards, etc.

My question is, in this scenario, how can $P(A), P(B)$ be updated to reflect this information?

Comment: Seems given info is intended to be for situations in which 1 to 4 yard runs are possible. You need different information for other situations. End zone play is bound to be different. (a) Maybe say $P(A_e) = .6/.8 = .75$ and $P(B_e) = .2/.8 = .25.$ (b) Maybe say P(A_e) = .6, P(B_e) = .2+.1+.1 = .4.$ (c) Maybe ask someone who knows more about football than I do.

Comment: Yes, that is true this could happen in any situation. Ex, 10 yards away from the end zone would yield 9 different probabilities, etc.